# How do I add a sidebar menu in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, web

So I want to make a sidebar menu with either HTML, CSS, or JavaScript to use in  a website. For example the W3 Schools website has a side menu and I would like to replicate that.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service, please try searching your question title in any good search provider and you will get a long list of tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a rule that tells you: If you can do something in CSS, then don't use JavaScript for it. And fortunately you can do it in CSS using `flexbox` layout. It simply lets you move, align, put simetrically elemnts on the page. Check this [flexbox cheat sheet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Take a look at this [Demo](https://jsbin.com/pifuqoy/5/edit?html,css,output):

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    height: 200px;
}
```

`display: flex` - makes `body` children affected by flex layout.

`flex-direction: row` - makes all the children align in a row. Possible values are: `row, row-reverse, column, column-reverse`.

```
body .side-bar {
    background-color:yellow;

    width: 150px
}

body .main-content {
    background-color: red;

    width: 100%
}
```

`width: 150px` - set the width of a sidebar.

`width: 100%` - set the width to fill the remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have created sidebars in the past was using html5 and css3 coding. I like that in html5 they have aside tags, nav tags and section tags.

I always use the navigation area for the main links list, usually spanning across the top of the page. However, when I want to include more than one navigation area such as a links list in a sidebar I will use the `<aside>` tags.

Using simple CSS3 coding you can setup the properties for your side bar sections pretty easily. the W3Schools website provides tons of tutorials for this.

I hope that helped you out a bit =) Best of luck to you.